# Issues with ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, polynomial-rings

We're trying to understand the field $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/\langle x^3+x^2+1 \rangle$, and in particular why it has eight elements. I know that $x^3+x^2+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and so factor is going to be a field.

The issue I'm having is that the notes claim that $(x+I)$ has an inverse in the field, where $I = \langle x^3+x^2+1 \rangle$. They write
$$
(x+I)(x^2+x+I)=x^3+x^2+I=1+I
$$
I don't understand the last line, I know that multiplication of cosets is defined that way, I just don't see why we get 1 at the end. I think it's possible I didn't fully understand cosets and ideals but I can't fully articulate what the issue is. Any help towards filling in the gaps of my understanding would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You get $1$ in the end, because $x^3+x^2=1$ by assumption for the quotient. Note that here $1=-1$ and $x^3+x^2+1=0$.

Comment: In congruence language: $\bmod (\color{#c00}2,\,x^3\!+\!x^2\!+\!1)\!:\,\ x(\color{#0a0}{x^2\!+\!x})\equiv \color{#c00}{-1\equiv 1}\,$ so $\,x^{-1}\equiv \color{#0a0}{x^2\!+\!x}\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might know that $a+I=b+I\,\iff a-b\in I$.

So $(x^{3}+x^{2})-1=(x^{3}+x^{2}+1)\in I$

So $(x^{3}+x^{2})+I=1+I$

also any element in   $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^{3}+x^{2}+1)$ is of the form $(ax^{2}+bx+c)+I$. There are $2$ choices for each $a,b,c$. So there are $8$ distinct elements in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ . This is because if you divide a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$ by a cubic polynomial, you get a remainder which is a quadratic polynomial of the form $ax^{2}+bx+c$.

So if $p(x)\in \mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$ then $p(x)=q(x)(x^{3}+x^{2}+1)+r(x)$ where $r(x)=ax^{2}+bx+c$. for some $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}_{2}$.

So $p(x)+I = ax^{2}+bx+c + I$ , as $q(x)(x^{3}+x^{2}+1)\in\langle x^{3}+x^{2}+1\rangle$ .

Comment: How can we know that any element in the field is going to have form$(ax^2+bx+c)$? I guess specifically why is the order limited to 2?

Comment: @eng2math By euclid's division algorithm

Comment: when you divide any polynomial by $x^{3}+x^{2}+1$. the remainder is a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: Also @eng2math . $\mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$ is **NOT** a field . It is an Euclidean Domain. $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ is a field. And for any field $\mathbb{F}$. the polynomial ring over it $\mathbb{F}[x]$ is a Euclidean domain and hence you can apply Euclid's division algorithm with the euclidean function being the degree of polynomial.

Comment: @eng2math I have edited my answer to include more detail .

Comment: So when I think of the factor field, I should be thinking of modding by $\langle x^3+x^2+1 \rangle$ as dividing the polynomials of $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ by the irreducible polynomial, and so the 8 elements of the field are then the equivalence classes of the remainders?

Comment: Yes exactly. Note that the polynomial $x^{3}+x^{2}+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$. So $\mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]/\langle x^{3}+x^{2}+1\rangle $ is a field . Because a commutative ring with unity modded by a maximal ideal is a field and $\mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$ is even stronger than that , it is an euclidean domain. You are expressing any polynomial as a product of $x^{3}+x^{2}+1 + $ some remainder. It is exactly the same as you would do when modding integers. $6=1.5 + 1 $ right....so $6+<5>$ in $\mathbb{Z}/<5>$ is $  1+<5>$ .

Comment: Awesome can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 2):

This is because $x^3 + x^2 + 1 \in I$ by definition and therefore $(x^3 + x^2 + 1) + I = I$ meaning that,
$$ (x^3 + x^2) + I = (x^3 + x^2) + (x^3 + x^2 + 1) + I = 1 + I $$
because the characteristic is $2$.